# Why is my Jwt token not being extracted?

Tags: express, mongoose, jwt, passport.js, express-jwt

I'm new to passport JWT and have this code sending post request from client:

```
export function checkLogin() {

  return function( dispatch ) {
  //check if user has token 
  let token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  if (token != undefined) {

    //fetch user deets
    var config = {
      headers: {'authorization': token, 'content-type': 'application/json'}
    };

    axios.post(`${API_URL}/login`, null, config)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('response is:', response);
    })
    .catch((error)=> {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
  //user is anonymous
}
```

and this request is sending off fine with token in headers like so:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
authorization:eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0NzIzMTg2MDE5NTd9.SsCYqK09xokzGHEVFiHtHmq5_HvtWkb8EjQJzwR937M
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json
DNT:1
Host:localhost:3090
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.23 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

On the server side, it is correctly routed through passport and hits this code:

```
// setup options for JWT strategy
const jwtOptions = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader('authorization'),
    secretOrKey: config.secret,
  ignoreExpiration: true
};

//create JWT strategy
const jwtLogin = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(payload, done ) {

 console.log('payload:',payload); // --> payload: { iat: 1472318601957 }

// see if the user ID in the payload exists in our database
  User.findById(payload.sub, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { 
      console.log('auth error');
      return done( err, false ); 
    }
    //if it does, call 'done' function with that user
    if (user) { 
      console.log('user authd:', user);
        done( null, user);
          //otherwise, call 'done' function without a user object
    } else {
      console.log('unauthd user'); //-->  gets here only
        done( null, false);
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that the extractJwt function only returns the iat portion and not the sub portion which I need to check the db.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by iat 1472318601957 ?

Comment: function tokenForUser(user) {
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  //subject and issued at time
  return jwt.encode({ sub: user.id, iat: timestamp }, config.secret);
}

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out.  I examined how my token generator function was working.  I'm using mongoose and it was passing the id of the user model to the token like this:

```
function tokenForUser(user) { 
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  //subject and issued at time 
  return jwt.encode({ sub: user.id, iat: timestamp }, config.secret);
}
```

I looked at the actual model that was being sent into this function and it turns out that mongoose adds an id with the key _id not id.  Once I changed it to this everything works!

```
function tokenForUser(user) {
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  //subject and issued at time
  const userid = user['_id'];
  return jwt.encode({ sub: userid, iat: timestamp }, config.secret);
}
```